# Local namespace not resolving in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, namespaces, razor-2

I have a project `Company.Web`and In the project there is a folder `Implementation`. Classes in this folder have the namespace `Company.Web.Implementation`.

The `_Layout.cshtml` file has the line

```
@using Company.Web.Implementation
```

The above line returns an error saying

> The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Company'

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
This appears to be occurring on any pages in the Web project where `Company.Web` is used.

Comment: It is a namespace in the same project. A project can't reference itself.

Comment: Oh my bad, misread

Comment: what version of .net do you use?

Comment: It's using v4.6.2 and it's in VS2017